# Is there a way to overwrite the lastPathSegment of an Uri?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to overwrite the last path segment of a pdf uri so that I can rename the file name after overwriting it with the new string.

I tried using

```
Uri.withAppendedPath(pdf.uri, docName)
```

But it's for appending the string path.
So can someone tell me if there's a way to do it or rather a way through which I can rename a pdf's name.

Comment: Use uri.toString() to get a string. Then you can change the last part. When ready use Uri.parse(path) to get an uri again.